# Firebase search find my value in under various children

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data in a firebase database, but the problem is my value is less then 3 children. Normally I am able to to search a value under the 1st child but I can't search under the 2nd and 3rd one.

Here is an example of what I have tried, but without result:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference mUserDatabase = database.getReference();
```

Query:

```
firebaseSearchQuery=mUserDatabase.orderByChild("Time").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");
```

Comment: Don't add information in the comments - [edit] it into the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Right. Look, the system supports a child reference -in the name/path of the child-, so just get a ref to the children and search on each.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference?authuser=0#child

```
var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('users');
var adaRef = usersRef.child('ada');
var adaFirstNameRef = adaRef.child('name/first');
var path = adaFirstNameRef.toString();
// path is now 'https://sample-app.firebaseio.com/users/ada/name/first'
```